# Blazor Webassembly IHostApplicationLifetime equivalent

Tags: hosted-blazor-webassembly

Is there any source for a `CancellationToken` in Blazor WebAssembly that signals the termination of the whole application - similar to `IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping`? If there is no such thing built-in what would be a good (best) practice to use instead?

*[Update - 23-12-25]*
I ended up creating my own with a CancelationTokenSource that is triggered when the `App` component is disposed of.